# HTML CSS how to set height 100%, width when expand 100% but when narrow the width it doesn't display full width

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to achieve what i want to do. It is pretty hard to fully describe what i mean but i have an example.

The situation
When the screen expands horizontally, the image is set to 100% width of the screen, but when it is reduced, it doesn't display the image fully,but keeping the height 100%.

I have attached an example below, that is exactly what i am thinking about.

```
http://www.therentscene.com/

     <script>
   var container=window;
         var image=document.getElementById("backimage")
         if (container.height() > container.width()) {
    image.css({height: container.height(), width: ''});
} else {
    image.css({height: '', width: container.width()});
}



  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use js/jQuery and find `max(container.h, container.w)` and apply that value to image itself

```
if (container.height() > container.width()) {
    image.css({height: container.height(), width: ''});
} else {
    image.css({height: '', width: container.width()});
}
```

Comment: I am not able to do it, cos i am not sure how to, but i put my attempt above, in the edit.

Comment: @user3829266 no, something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/mGXp6/